# Windows Form app displaying an SSRS report

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, reporting-services

I am trying to run an SSRS report in my Windows application. When I attempt to run the report, I get "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." The report will not load in my application but I can log into my report server with my Windows credentials and run all of the reports just fine. I have also discovered if I look in the Report Server Execution Log after I attempt to run this report from the Windows App that there is an entry that returned success.

Here is the Exception my application throws:
Source      : Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Method      : GetSecureMethods
Date/Time   : 9:54:20 AM 2/4/2011
Message     : The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
Stack Trace : at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at InvoiceTracking.ucCustomerLookup.btnViewAll_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Anyone have any thoughts to where I do not have access to view the report in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had stored my windows credentitals on our reporting services website. I have changed my password since setting that authentication, which is why it was failing. I found the stored credentials by going to Control Panel>User Accounts>Advance Tab>Manage Passwords.

I hope someone else finds this helpful